# MVC3: jquery ajax to return partial view with HTML dataType from controller but getting error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need some help. I am returning partial view as HTML dataType from controller action when calling it from jQuery ajax on button click event.

This is my Javascript tag from my main view:

```
$(function () {
     $('#searchButton').click(function () {
        var DTO = {
            Name: $('#Name').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Grid/GetSearch',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            data: DTO,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //Fill div with results
                $("#SearchViewDiv").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetSearch(string name)
    {
        var accounts = _userAccounts.FindAll(x => x.Name.Contains(name));
        return PartialView("SearchResult", accounts);
    }
```

I am able to debug this controller when jQuery ajax is making call to this action but when it is returning I am getting into error function of jQuery Ajax. So guessing target URL is correct. But not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Please let me know if more info is required.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Dzmitry for your inputs. But I figured out the solution.

Issue: Problem was page was reloading after button click that was causing Ajax call to be getting cancelled while returning this partial view response.

Solution: Just adding event.preventDefault() solved this problem.
So Javascript snippet will look like this,

```
$('#searchButton').click(function (e) {
        var DTO = {
            Name: $('#Name').val()
        };
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Grid/GetSearch',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            data: DTO,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //Fill div with results
                $("#SearchViewDiv").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#searchButton').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@(Url.Action("GetSearch"))",
            type: "GET",
            data: { name: $("#Name").val() },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //Fill div with results
                $("#SearchViewDiv").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and this...

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetSearch(string name)
{
    return PartialView("SearchResult", _userAccounts.Where(u => u.Name.Contains(name)));
}
```

Controller action parameters case sensivity are important (string name != string Name). Also in html and jquery: "#Name" not the same as "#name" in id field. Be warned...

Comment: is it right way to get URL  in JS 

 url: "@(Url.Action("GetSearch"))",

Answer (score 0):

If your button is an actual "button" element instead of an "input" element, then make sure you add type="button" to the button, otherwise it defaults to type="submit", and the form/page will get posted on click of that button.  By changing the type to "button", then nothing happens on click other that your handler code.